# How to convert titlesec code to scrlayer-scrpage code

Tags: titlesec, scrlayer-scrpage

In my LaTeX code I use the actual version of the KOMA-script bundle and its documentclass scrbook. In this regard I wonder how to convert code which uses the package titlesec to code which should use the more KOMA-script compatible scrlayer-scrpage package. Please, find the relevant code below. I would be very grateful if anybody can help me!

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
%modify part-page-style
\titleformat{\part}[display]
    {\huge\filcenter\bfseries}
    {\Huge{\MakeUppercase{\partname} \thepart}}
    {5pt}
    {\titlerule[3pt] \vspace{10pt}}
    []
%modify chapter-page-style
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\LARGE\filcenter\bfseries}
    {\titlerule[3pt] \vspace{3pt} \titlerule[1pt] \vspace{5pt} \huge{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}}
    {0pt}
    {\titlerule[1pt] \vspace{10pt}}
    []
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a suggestion that needs [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) **version 3.17** (the current version on CTAN) or newer:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}[2015/04/23]
\usepackage{microtype}
% modify part
\setkomafont{part}{\normalfont\bfseries\huge}
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\normalfont\bfseries\Huge}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[innerskip=10pt]{part}
\renewcommand\partformat{%
  \strut\MakeUppercase{\lsstyle% Upper case sequences should be spaced
    \partname~\thepart}%
  \vspace{5pt}\hrule height 3pt%
}
% modify chapter
\KOMAoptions{chapterprefix}
\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\centering}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries\LARGE}
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\huge}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=40pt,innerskip=12pt]{chapter}
\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  \hrule height 3pt\vspace{3pt}\hrule height 1pt\vspace{5pt}%
  \mbox{\strut\MakeUppercase{\lsstyle% Upper case sequences should be spaced
      \chapapp\nobreakspace\thechapter}}%
  \hrule height 1pt%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Part title}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

---

Note, that the `inner skip` option was introduced in KOMA-Script version 3.17. So with **version 3.15 or 3.16** (current version in MiKTeX and TeX Live 2014) you have to use

```
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{\vspace{10pt}}
```

and

```
\renewcommand\chapterheadmidvskip{\vspace{12pt}}
```

instead. This works also with version 3.17 or newer.

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}[2015/01/01]
\usepackage{microtype}
% modify part
\setkomafont{part}{\normalfont\bfseries\huge}
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\normalfont\bfseries\Huge}
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{\vspace{10pt}}
\renewcommand\partformat{%
  \strut\MakeUppercase{\lsstyle% Upper case sequences should be spaced
    \partname~\thepart}%
  \vspace{5pt}\hrule height 3pt%
}
% modify chapter
\KOMAoptions{chapterprefix}
\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\centering}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries\LARGE}
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\huge}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=40pt]{chapter}
\renewcommand\chapterheadmidvskip{\vspace{12pt}}
\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  \hrule height 3pt\vspace{3pt}\hrule height 1pt\vspace{5pt}%
  \mbox{\strut\MakeUppercase{\lsstyle% Upper case sequences should be spaced
      \chapapp\nobreakspace\thechapter}}%
  \hrule height 1pt%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Part title}
\blinddocument
\end{document}


\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{microtype}
% modify part
\setkomafont{part}{\normalfont\bfseries\huge}
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\normalfont\bfseries\Huge}
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{\vspace{10pt}}
\renewcommand\partformat{%
  \strut\MakeUppercase{\lsstyle% Upper case sequences should be spaced
    \partname~\thepart}%
  \vspace{5pt}\hrule height 3pt%
}
% modify chapter
\KOMAoptions{chapterprefix}
\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\centering}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries\LARGE}
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\huge}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=40pt]{chapter}
\renewcommand\chapterheadmidvskip{\vspace{12pt}}
\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  \hrule height 3pt\vspace{3pt}\hrule height 1pt\vspace{5pt}%
  \mbox{\strut\MakeUppercase{\lsstyle% Upper case sequences should be spaced
      \chapapp\nobreakspace\thechapter}}%
  \hrule height 1pt%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Part title}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, KOMA-script has a `\RedeclareSectionCommand` which provides a similar interface to `titlesec`. Consult the manual, chapter 21.